# Snowflake staging Error "Reason: unable to upload the file to s3"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using a trial version of Snowflake and I am using snowflake default staging(i don't have a different s3 or other cloud storage). I've uploaded 50% of my data but now I'm getting this error:
File is not large (less than 20mb).
[image]

Also tried Python-based approach :

```
cnx ...
...
def uploader(d,d_name):
sql  = pd.io.sql.get_schema(d, d_name).replace("CREATE TABLE","CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE")
print(cnx.cursor().execute(sql).fetchall())

cnx.cursor().execute(f"PUT file:///content/test/{d_name}* @%{d_name}")
cnx.cursor().execute(f"""COPY INTO {d_name} from '@%{d_name}/{d_name}.csv.gz' FILE_FORMAT = '"A_DB"."PUBLIC"."A_FORM"' ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = TRUE;""").fetchall()
```

Comment: (1) Are you loading data into S3 so that you can import it into Snowflake or are you trying to export data from Snowflake into S3? (2) What do you mean by "snowflake default staging"? Snowflake has default stages for users and tables but these have nothing to do with S3 (or at least, not directly) (3) When you say you've uploaded 50% of your data, do you mean 50% of 1 file or 50% of a number of files?

Comment: @NickW 1 :- I am loadig data from a csv, I've tried gui and python connector both.
2. "snowflake default staging" mean : I have no s3 account and also i havn't created any.
3. I had multiple tables and 9 out of 10 uploaded sucessfully but 10 showing me this error.

Comment: (1) If you take one of the files that you have loaded successfully, re-name it and then load it - does that work? This should show whether it is a generic load issue or a problem with the specific file (2) What command are you running when you are using the GUI? There is no such thing as Snowflake default staging so you must be loading into a table, user or named stage

Comment: I segmented that file into 60 files and then uploaded them one by one. I think snowflake has some file size limitations on the free trial.
2. I am not running any command I am using the load data option.

Comment: Do you mean you were using the Snowflake UI: Databases > Tables > Load Data... ? If you were then this has a 50Mb limit - as is clearly stated in the documentation here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-web-ui.html . If you have a local file that you want to load into Snowflake, it is much better practice to push it to a named/table stage and COPY it from there. This process is explained here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system.html

Comment: I tried Table staging as well but I'm surprised after 4 tables it didn't work. Basically, I created a Function that takes Table name and Dataframe and do all processing but it worked for 4 tables and after that, it didn't work,I am adding that function too with Question.